# Flow of water in a container

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, liquid-state

We all know, liquids flow from high pressure to low pressure.(which is a fallacy) And now assume a glass of water. The pressure at the bottom will be surely greater than that at the top. Then why doesn't the water flow from bottom to top?

PS. I already know that liquids flow to attain the least energetic configuration. In the above example the gravitational potential energy is the balancing potential that stops the flow. But when I try to explain it to my friends they don't find it intuitive. Can you please help me with a more subtle explaination!

Comment: The pressure below has to support the weight of the water above.

Answer (score 2):

The idea that "liquid flows from high pressure to low pressure" is simply wrong. A positive pressure gradient by itself can generate an *acceleration* of fluid particles in the opposite direction of the pressure gradient, but like you say, the resultant force from the pressure gradient may be balanced by other forces, such as gravitation. Overall, acceleration is proportional to the *sum* of pressure gradient, viscous, and volume forces.

Moreover, quite obviously, particle velocity does not need to be in the same direction as acceleration. For example, in an expanding pipe, pressure may increase in the direction of the flow. This corresponds to the flow slowing down (negative acceleration), but the flow may still be in the direction of increasing pressure.